# Bootstrap Print Modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to style bootstrap modal for print.

The page opening modal has scroll and depending on scroll position, print preview gives extra margin on top.

Any suggestion or advice?

Comment: is it a fullscreen modal or with backdrop?

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban it is modal with backdrop

Comment: @smchae Did you tried anything..? If possible please provide your fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I handled this was to add a class to background div before printing. Then in my styles I give `display: none !important` to that class in `media query` for `print`:

```
@media print { 
    /* All your print styles go here */
    .hide { display: none !important; } 
}
```

And before printing:

```
$("#divtohide").addClass("hide");
```

After printing:

```
$("#divtohide").removeClass("hide");
```